# How to map keras input sequence to multi-label vector

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

How can I create a layer in Keras (I am using the functional API) that transforms an input sequence to a multi-label vector. The layer must execute the mapping, I don't want to learn the mapping by learning parameter weights.

As input I have vectors as shown here in **keras**:

```
[  nan   nan   nan   nan   nan   nan  342.  367.  453. 1971.   nan   nan
   nan   nan   2]
```

and I need to map the **first 10** numbers of the input vector to a vector that looks like this:

```
[x1 =0,x2=0,..., x342=1, ..., x367=1,... x453=1,... x1971=1,... xN]
```

How can I create a layer that can do this? Is there an existing layer for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part about choosing 10 numbers can be accompliced by this code using a *Lambda* layer:

```
take_n_layer=Lambda(lambda z: z[:, :len(classes)], name='take_n', output_shape=(None, 10))(input_layer)
```

The second question about mapping the input can be done by using a *CategoryEncoding* layer with the *output_mode* **binary**:

```
input_categoric_encoding = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.CategoryEncoding(max_tokens=num_skills, output_mode="binary")
```